# WooCommerce пропали поля для ввода карты. Как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang, stripe

Пропали поля, куда нужно по идеи вводить данные карточки. То-есть там номер, CVC код и дата, ну как и везде. Как вернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал скачать этот плагин на другой мой сайт, там все поля отображались. Я скачал с этого сайта эту папку и загрузил на второй сайт (на котором не работают поля) - полей нет. То-есть дело не в настройке плагина, а в WooCommerce как я понял.

На сайте я так-же пользуюсь плагином polylang, для перевода. Я лазил в папках WooCommerce, переводил, походу что-то задел не то. Без понятие, как исправить.
Плагин для оплаты называется "woocommerce-gateway-stripe".

Comment: Поставьте плагин с репозитория и настройте его согласно инструкции.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Когда я загуглил это, мне сразу вышло, как загрузить правильно свой плагин. То-есть если он у меня уже есть. А что вы имеете ввиду, я не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, обычным переходом с http на https.

Comment: Не могу сделать вариант ответа, как правильный. Если модераторы тут, выберите как верный ответ.